# Stored procedure in MDX

Tags: mdx

It is possible to create stored procedure in MDX (Microsoft Analysis Serwer) the same like in MS SQL? I created simply query in MDX and now I would like to use this query to build stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there are stored procedures as such.

What we use is this project compiled into SQL Server:

https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can have a .NET function running in SSAS Multidimensional as a "stored proc" but it won't easily achieve the same thing as they are wanting. https://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/ Anyway, you are right that there are no spocs.

Comment: Thanks Greg for confirming my feeling about lack of sprocs like tsql

Answer (score 0):

There is no stored procedure in MDX.